# Joomap (on joomla) causes 404 error if it is menulink case

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla1.5

I'm using Joomla 1.5 and installed Joomap to create site map.

I found that if the item in the Joomap tree is a menulink (menu alias), then it cannot work as deserved. 
It will cause a 404 error which said the component cannot be found when the menulink is clicked.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, This is the solution.

All you need to do is to modify the component code, just by commenting one line your problem will be solved.  There is no other way.

```
Edit : /components/joomap/joomap.html.php
```

and comment the line of code, around line number 58, 59

```
$link .= '&amp;Itemid='.$node->id;
```

to

```
//$link .= '&amp;Itemid='.$node->id;
```

Just comment the line and it will work as it deserve.

Hope this will solve your answer.
SIA